# Problems with QT commandline (system or qprocess)

Tags: c++, qt, ipython, system, conda

So I have an image recognition deep learning model, for which I prepared a GUI in QT. I need to run a script with ipython, which loads the model, and outputs a single number. Now that single number is what I want to have in the QT application. 
So without the unnecesarry story: I want to run a script via QT and get the output in a string(first).

Using g++ with terminal, I could run system(), and it outputed the number I wanted to, so that worked fine, thus the problem cannot be with my code, nor the command itself.

```
std::string valInString;
std::string str = "ipython /home/szalontaibal/Dokumentumok/DeepLearning/fastai/fastai/courses/dl1/moneyqt.py";
const char *command = str.c_str();
valInString = exec(command);
std::cout << valInString;
```

I tried process.execute(...), process.start(...) and system(...) as well, but they could only run basic commands (gedit, ls, etc.), but not ipython. In other words, the code shown before won't work in QT.

Sometimes it got stuck, sometimes the output was something like ipython was not found.

One other strange thing. As said before, i have a c++ program which can do what I want. I tried running that with the same method, but it was complaining about not finding ipython, where on the other hand, the mentioned c++ program was working perfectly (when opened manually, not via qt)

One other thing I can think of. I need to have conda activated before executing the script with ipython, maybe that's not activated via qt?
But even if I add "conda activate && ...." to the front, it says conda is not found.

Comment: If you start `ipython` on command line (in a shell) then the environment variable `PATH` is considered. This is also done in `system()` but not in `exec()` nor in `QProcess`. If on Linux (and it looks like), you could do `which ipython` to get the ful path of `ipython`. Then use that absolute path in `exec()` or `QProcess` and look whether it becomes better. (I wouldn't wonder.)

Comment: I just noticed your statement that even `system()` failed to locate `ipython`. May be, the `system()` uses a different environment than your shell. (There are personal shell scripts considered at shell start where the `PATH` may be extended for interactive sessions and I'm not sure if `system()` considers that. On the other hand, a process started from such shell should inherit the environment of the shell. So, it's just a shot into blue...)